# Wordpress text module (widget)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a web site on Wordpress using my custom made theme, I need to put a module with text and images on the frontpage of my theme which should be managed from the admin panel. I've read about widgets but I don't quite get how can I put them anywhere not just in sidebars, I don't have sidebars on my frontpage. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget compatible sidebar in Wordpres it is just position on the page where widget could be placed. It is not necessary to be in the left or right column of the site. I could be anywhere(header, footer, middle part). Look on the default theme how sidebars created in it. Default theme has 7 or 8 positions(sidebars) for widgets accessable from admin. Also there are lots of tutorials on how to add sidebar into theme

http://www.blogohblog.com/adding-extra-sidebar-to-your-wordpress-theme/,

http://www.balkhis.com/web-designs-resources/how-to-add-a-dynamic-sidebar-in-wordpress/

and many others.